# Multiple filters while doing Sum in XSLT 1

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt, xslt-1.0, xpath-1.0

XML :

```
<A>
    <B>
        <C name="test name1" age="10">
            <id>1</id>
            <address/>
        </C>
        <C name="test name2" age="20">
            <id>2</id>
            <address>test address</address>
        </C>
        <C name="test name3" age="30">
            <id>3</id>
            <address/>
        </C>
    </B>
</A>
```

In this XML, I want to get the sum of all C's age where name doesn't contain a String & address is empty.

XSLT/XPath snippets that I've tried :

```
<xsl:variable name="total-age" select="sum(A/B/C[not(contains(@name,'testString')) and (address = '')]/@age)" />
```

and

```
<xsl:variable name="total-age" select="sum(A/B/C[not(contains(@name,'testString'))] [address = '']/@age)" />
```

If I use just one filter say `<xsl:variable name="total-age" select="sum(A/B/C [address = '']/@age)" />` or `<xsl:variable name="total-age" select="sum(A/B/C[not(contains(@name,'testString'))]/@age)" />` It'll work for that particular filter however when I add both the filters it's not working. How to make both the filters work ? I'm using **XSLT/XPATH 1** version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to get the sum of all C's age where name doesn't contain a String & address is empty.

I believe that would be:

```
sum(/A/B/C[not(contains(@name,'testString')) and not(address/text())]/@age)
```

Comment: It's not working. If I try any one filter it gives result for that particular filter. However with both the filters in place it's not working.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "not working". It works for me when I try it with your input -  so there must be something you are doing differently and not telling us.

Comment: sorry my bad ! I just now took my actual xml snippet and ran it , it worked with your solution and it ran with my earlier XSLT too ( two of which is provided with my question) But when I run my whole xml, it's not working ! Let me figure out what's going wrong ! Thanks a lot for your input. Accepting your answer.